# SQL Server sp_who shows last workstation to link tables hostname instead of present workstation hostname

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've got an Access front end to SQL Server 2008, when I exec sp_who to see who's using it in what manner all the workstation ID's show my workstation ID. I'm guessing this is because the last person to link all the remote tables was in fact, me.

Is there a way to fix this?  It's not TERRIBLE that it's happening but it just seems like there's an easy way to resolve this.

I do pass the actual workstation ID on to multiple queries on the back end so that when things get deleted, they're only for the present user (and not some other users data).

Also in my logon form for the front end I tried to link just one table via VBA code to see if that would remedy the problem, but it seemingly did not.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server authentication instead of Windows authentication? I would always use Windows authentication when it's available, as it just makes life a lot easier. That said, it doesn't sound right to me that the workstation would be included in the link -- I'd think only user credentials would be involved, and workstation is not one of them.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server authentication. I have a couple workstations that get used by multiple users, so Windows Auth doesn't go over well with that.

Comment: I don't understand. If they are authorized users of your network, they have a Windows logon. All you have to do is create user groups for your database users and then set up your SQL Server security/roles to use the NTFS security groups (which many people mistakenly call Active Directory user groups -- AD is just an interface to NTFS that extends its functionality).

Comment: Mostly because the workstations that are shared by a couple people, they aren't going to want to log out/log in of the workstation to be under their username.

Comment: But don't they log in with the SQL credentials? If not, then why do you care what they are logged on as?

Comment: They log in with SQL Credentials, but there are several parts of the program that'll ask who you are, in case you are not the original logged in user to 'set' the user creating the new data appropriately.  I think they did this so that if you were using shared workstations you'd have a way log in as anyone but still be able to 'do your own work'.

Comment: Sounds like a poorly-managed working environment (to me, sharing a workstation logon is a sign of something wrong).

Comment: There are several people that share a/a couple computer(s).  It's not like a row of cubicles with not enough computers per user.  They aren't on them all the time, just to add data to the system and proceed with their work. The workstation login is just named as a location, not a specific user.  It's fine for what we do.

Comment: But in a properly-run environment, they should be logging off and logging on as themselves. I understand this is not something you control, but what you're running into (i.e., being forced to use SQL Server authentication and managing the logon in your app) is one of many consequences of the poor management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the code to pass the WSID along with the ODBC connection string and re-link tables on first open fixes this.